# Which alternatives to ASM can I use to code some parts of a kernel?

Tags: kernel, osdev

I initially considered using FORTH, or Haskell but I just wanted to know if there are any other ASM languages I can use as an alternative.  I intend on using Lua and/or for the higher level parts of the kernel, and the applications themselves.

Comment: Have you read the [Languages](https://wiki.osdev.org/Languages) page from the OSDev wiki? It discusses which languages are suited for OS-Dev as-is, and what it would take to support or adapt other languages for kernel development.

Comment: In short, assuming that the OS is running on stock hardware (e.g., a PC), then for whatever language you are using you would need to have either a native-code compiler, or a lower-level OS to act as the interpreter for the language, or some combination of the two. Furthermore, some parts of an OS - specifically those regarding system tables for things such as paging - require the ability to set an exact data structure up in memory. There are even some things which can *only* be done in assembly language, regardless of the OS in question, though fortunately these are becoming less common.

Comment: There have been specialized hardware platforms which provided specific support for a given language, such as the Burroughs mainframes from the 1960s, or the Lisp Machines from the 1980s, or the Lilith Workstation (also from the 1980s), but none of those are still in common use today.

Comment: To sum up, any use of a language such as Lua or Haskell would require at least as much work on a specialized language implementation, and modifications to the language proper, as on the OS itself. Forth is a bit of an anomaly in this, due to how the usual Forth interpreter operates (and the fact that Forth invariably includes an assembler as part of the Forth implementation), but even then the same more or less applies.